# Custom "Amount" in PayPal form

Tags: php, paypal

I would like my user to insert an "Amount" to donate on my website and when they click the "Donate" button it opens up the PayPal website in a new tab with the amount already filled in from my website.

The donation works, it's just not inserting the "Amount" they filled in on my website on the new PayPal tab.

I created a button in PayPal and am using the "hosted_button_id" option. Is this why it does not work?

PHP:

```
echo '<form name="DonateForm" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_blank">',
        '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">',
        '<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="MY_BUTTON_ID">',
        '<fieldset>',
            '<ul>',
                '<li>',
                    '<label class="label" for="custom">User ID:</label>',
                    '<input class="text" type="text" name="custom" id="custom" value="',$users->id,'">',
                '</li>',
                '<li>',
                    '<label class="label" for="amount">Amount:</label>',
                    '<input class="text" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="0.00">',
                '</li>',
                '<li>',
                    '<input class="submit-donate" type="submit" name="DonateForm" value="Donate">',
                '</li>',
            '</ul>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</form>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot over-ride the amount value in a hosted button.Use clear text instead.

```html
<form name="DonateForm" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
       <input type="hidden" name="business" value="vimaluk@gmail.com"><!-- -Insert your business email address or payer id -->
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label class="label" for="custom">User ID:</label>
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="custom" id="custom" value="11">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="label" for="amount">Amount:</label>
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="0.00">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="submit-donate" type="submit" name="DonateForm" value="Donate">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: I use PayPals IPN, I assume this works with _donations? I can't find the differences between _donations and _xclick (besides one of for "Donation" and the other is "Buy Now")